# linking error - suffix @

Tags: c++, windows, hyperlink, lnk2019, suffix

I have two lib files based on C++, one given from a company and another compiled by myself using the source code provided by the company. I am using Windows 7 x64 and compiling the library using makefile.

When I try to link a program using the library that I compiled, it produces an error (LNK 2019:unresolved external symbol) complaining that it cannot find a function in the library.

The problem I found is that the name of the function that the linker is looking for has a @-suffix, but the library I compiled doesn't have that suffix. If I use the library provided by the company, it has the @-suffix and works fine. So I would like to know what this @-suffix means and how to compile the library so that it has that suffix.

Thank for reading and any help will be greatly appreciated.

ps. Belows are the initial parts of the dumpbin output, where the upper one is from the library from the company and the lower one is the one I complied:

**Library from the company**

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.30723.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file motor.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

Archive member name at 8: /               
5602DBD6 time/date Wed Sep 23 18:05:26 2015
         uid
         gid
       0 mode
   29F93 size
correct header end

    5179 public symbols

    51FA4 _S826_WriteReg@12
    51FA4 __imp__S826_WriteReg@12
    52010 _S826_WriteBridge@24
    52010 __imp__S826_WriteBridge@24
    5207E _S826_WatchdogWaitCancel@4
    5207E __imp__S826_WatchdogWaitCancel@4
```

**Library I compiled**

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.30723.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file motor.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

Archive member name at 8: /               
56796705 time/date Tue Dec 22 15:06:45 2015
         uid
         gid
       0 mode
   2A45B size
correct header end

    5252 public symbols

    52368 S826_WriteReg
    52368 __imp_S826_WriteReg
    523D0 S826_WriteBridge
    523D0 __imp_S826_WriteBridge
    5243A S826_WatchdogWaitCancel
    5243A __imp_S826_WatchdogWaitCancel
```

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ name mangling".

Comment: That's not C++ name mangling; that's Win32 __stdcall name mangling.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: That's being remarkably pedantic, considering there is no such thing as C++ name mangling. Thomas was clearly speaking generally.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I don't think it's pedantic at all. If you want to understand what _those_ suffixes are, you need to know about Win32 `__stdcall` mangling, which applies to C _and_ C++.